# SSIS Script Task with Read/Write Variables doesn't stop on ScriptResults.Failure

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, script-task

If I don't pass any variables to the script task, I can make it fail or succeed by setting the Dts.TaskResult. But When I pass some read/write variables, I can't make it fail (keeps executing forever), but I can still make it succeed.

Am I missing some settings? Please help.

I am using Sql Server 2012 (VS 2010 for BIDS). 
Script code:

```
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
return;
```

Read/write variable passed:

```
User::FileName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hadi,
Thank you so much for responding, really appreciate it. 
I saw similar lock issues in other posts, tried it and failed. But I was able to understand the root cause myself later and I'm posting it so that it might save time for somebody else:

I realized later that, in addition to above script task and readwrite variable, I had also used that ReadWrite variable in error handling event of the whole package. When a ReadWrite variable used in SSIS package is used in Error Handler, it makes the package to NOT fail even when exceptions happen or Dts.TaskResult is set to fail. Instead, it goes running in infinite loop! pretty wacky, eh? I wish Microsoft had planned to return some kind of validation error for using ReadWrite variable of script task in Error handler instead of an infinite execution...

Anyway, I solved the problem by not using that ReadWrite variable in script task and setting it in some Expression task to be used by error handler.

Answer (score 1):

*The issue may be caused by a variable deadlock*

Try setting the variable value using the following code:

```
Variables lockedVariables = null;
 Dts.VariableDispenser.LockOneForWrite("FileName", ref lockedVariables);
lockedVariables["FileName"].Value = "bla bla bla"; 
lockedVariables.Unlock();
```

And remove the variable from the script `ReadWriteVariables`

Comment: btw, this might work too since you are suggesting I could remove that variable from ReadWrite list. I hadn't tried removing the variable from ReadWrite list when I used similar code for locking/unlocking variable in script task.  Will try it in some other package. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Sumanasa happy getting your problem solved. Your answer is like a workaround. Not best way to solve the issue. Good luck

Comment: Tried above code and removed variable from ReadWrite list in another package. But script task still goes into infinite loop without failing:( .. looks like it is a bug on SSIS:( :(... Anyway, expression task was good enough for me since I just had to set filename based on fully qualified path. I do file checking part in script task afterwards, that way script task is free to fail for exceptions and error handler does its processing with filename.